# How to make a random number generator in 3.23 with levels of difficulty

Tags: python, random, integer, generator

```
#Guess the number game by Johnathan Millsap
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 100)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')
print('Try to guess it!.')

while guessesTaken <= 3:
    print('Take a guess.')
    guesesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

if guess < number:
    print('Your guess is too low.')     
if guess > number:
    print('Your guess is too high.')
if guess == number:


if guess == number:
    guesesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

The main problem im having with this is it keeps telling me my int wont convert into the string implicitly... im also trying to do this in three different difficulties like 1-100 and 1-1000 and 1-10000. ANY help on this would be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lab4.py", line 28, in <module>
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
Terminated with exit code 1.
```

Comment: what's the exact error? Post the whole traceback in question body.

Comment: Also fix your indentation (or is this actually how it's indented?)

Comment: Thank you guys a ton... that was driving me insane. Im very new to python and I appreciate the help!

Comment: I need to configure this to also respond accordingly to how many tries the user takes to get the correct number such as <=3 "Great work! You are a mathematical wizard." and >3 and <=7 "Not too bad! You've got some potential." and also >7 "What took you so long?"  Thanks for any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the indentation is messed-up in the question, and it's correct in your assignment's file (Lab4.py)
Try:

```
print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a typographical error in your code

```
guesesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
```

should be

```
guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the int to a string using str()L

```
print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
```